# Sqlite.net JSON extension syntax

Tags: json, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm trying to understand how the Sqlite JSON extensions work. Lets say a company has several branches and each branch has a catalogue of stock, so I create a table like:-

```
SQL = "CREATE TABLE BranchStock (branch VARCHAR, stock JSON)"
....
```

I then insert a few items like:-

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO BranchStock (branch, stock) values('Melbourne', json_array(json_object('catnumber', 'ABC123', 'instock',2), json_object('catnumber', 'BCD321', 'instock',5)))"
....

SQL = "INSERT INTO BranchStock (branch, stock) values('Sydney', json_array(json_object('catnumber', 'ABC123', 'instock',5), json_object('catnumber', 'XYZ567', 'instock',3)))"
....
```

Now I'm looking for the search sql to list which branches have the catnumber='ABC123', and the instock amounts. Perhaps something like this:-

```
SQL = "SELECT branch, json_extract(stock, '$[].instock') FROM BranchStock WHERE json_valid(stock) AND json_extract(stock, '$[].catnumber') = 'ABC123'
```

Can someone help me with the correct SELECT syntax?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't recommend actually using this for anything that's going to be run frequently or on huge tables, but if you absolutely have to...

Given the following test table:

```
CREATE TABLE BranchStock(branch TEXT, stock TEXT);
INSERT INTO BranchStock VALUES('Melbourne','[{"catnumber":"ABC123","instock":2},{"catnumber":"BCD321","instock":5}]');
INSERT INTO BranchStock VALUES('Sydney','[{"catnumber":"ABC123","instock":5},{"catnumber":"XYZ567","instock":3}]');
```

Getting the branches and instock number for stores with `'ABC123'`:

```
SELECT branch, json_extract(value, '$.instock') AS instock
FROM BranchStock JOIN json_each(stock)
WHERE json_extract(value, '$.catnumber') = 'ABC123';
```

gives

```
branch      instock   
----------  ----------
Melbourne   2         
Sydney      5
```

It'd be a lot easier and more efficient to do pretty much anything using a table definition like

```
CREATE TABLE BranchStock(branch TEXT, catid TEXT, instock INTEGER);
```

instead of trying to search through JSON data stored in a column. For example:

```
SELECT branch, instock FROM BranchStock WHERE catid = 'ABC123';
```

especially when you start adding indexes into the mix.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for. I take your point that it is **not** the solution for performance - but it does offer a simple db design... Thanks again.